# Set current_page? with multistep form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to set a [current_page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F#322-with-resources) rule to show a line in a specific page of a Rails app with a multistep form

My **URLs** look like:

http://localhost:3000/orders/order_id/steps/initial_data
http://localhost:3000/orders/order_id/steps/final_order
http://localhost:3000/orders/order_id/steps/checkout

And I'm only trying to pass a specific line in the URL ending in /initial_data, not the rest of steps

My **routes** are:

```
   order_step GET        /orders/:order_id/steps/:id(.:format)        order/steps#show
              PATCH      /orders/:order_id/steps/:id(.:format)        order/steps#update
              PUT        /orders/:order_id/steps/:id(.:format)        order/steps#update
       orders GET        /orders(.:format)                            orders#index
              POST       /orders(.:format)                            orders#create
         root GET        /                                            orders#create
```

Tried with:

```
  <% unless current_page?('/orders/:order_id/steps/inital_data') %>
  something
  <% else %>
  something else
  <% end %>
```

But it renders always the 'something' in all the steps of the form, no matter if they end in /initial_data or not.

Comment: I guess you are using actual `:order_id` and `initial_data` without "**"?

Comment: Yes, those were just bold text, just edited that in the post.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, but first, what do the `params` look like after visiting each of the links?